# How to use job scheduler with calendar time to run job at particular time

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

if i am doing something like 10 * 1000, then this code is working but not with calendar.getTimeInMillis(), i need to generate PN in future based on calendar time and Alam Manger is not looking good (Checked on Android P and its not working ) as per new Android updation on background services.

---

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 10); JobInfo info = new 

JobInfo.Builder(1231, componentName).setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).setOverrideDeadline(calendar.getTimeInMillis()).setMinimumLatency(calendar.getTimeInMillis()).setRequiresCharging(false).setBackoffCriteria(10 * 1000, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR).setExtras(persistableBundle).build();
```

I am trying to run job scheduler a/c calendar time, but looks like its not working.

Comment: `JobScheduler` cannot run a job at a particular time.

Comment: i believe it can if use setOverrideDeadline() and setMinimumLatency()

Comment: Here is the solution for my question:  final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(GpShopperApplication.getAppContext(), CountdownJobService.class);
        final JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setOverrideDeadline(timeTillFutureJob)
                .setMinimumLatency(timeTillFutureJob)
                .setExtras(persistableBundle)
                .build();

Comment: With Doze mode and app standby, there is no guarantee that your job will run at that time.